# How to check for a specific character in an inputed list in python

Tags: list, loops, python-3.x, count

I've been trying to find a way to do this but don't know how, I want to have a function such as:

```
def counter(inputted_list):
```

where the user calls the function with a list as a parameter. When that list is inputted the body of the function counts the amount of a specific character in the list, such as the amount of capital C's, I've tried using `i=0` and then a for loop. When 'C' is found: `i=i+1` with `print(i)` at the end but can't get it to work.

Comment: `inputted_list.count("C")`? `["A", "B", "C", "B", "A"].count("C")` returns `1`.

Comment: The thing is is the list that is inputted can be something like ['Cat','cool','Computer','baby'] and it will still check how many capital C's there are

Answer (score 0):

Simple one liner using [`str.count`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.count) method, [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) built-in function.

```
sum(s.count("C") for s in list_of_strings)
```